# How to edit check-boxes without losing existing values

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

I am building a job app with rails. In creating a new company, a user has the ability to select perks associated with the company in the "Company new page" through checkboxes. Ths works well until a user tries to update/edit the perks associated with a company.

When a user tries to edit the perks, the edit method completely removes existing values even though the user did not uncheck them in the  edit page. So for example, a company has perks such as pension and free lunch. The user decides to edit this and add health insurance to the already existing perks. The edit method in this instance deletes pension and free lunch and only save health insurance despite the user not unchecking pension and free lunch. What i want is for he edit/update method to save the new checked values in addition to the already existing ones provided they were not unchecked. Below is a sample code in the edit page

```
<% Perk.all.each do |perk| %>
  <input type="checkbox", class="hidden", value="<%= perk.id %>" 
  name="company[perk_ids][]" id="company_perk_ids_<%= perk.id %>"/>
  <label class="category-choice <%= "active" if 
  @company.perk_ids.include? perk.id %>" for="company_perk_ids_<%= 
  perk.id %>">
   <% perk.name %>
  </label
<% end %>
```

This is the sample code in my companies controller

```
  def edit
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    edit
    @company.update(company_params)
    if @company.update(company_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Company profile successfully updated."
      redirect_to @company
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

And in my js, I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".category-choice").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're probably hiding the actual checkboxes and instead displaying an image based on the `active` class on the label to show its current state.  The problem with that is that the `active` class isn't correctly indicating the checked state of the box (because you're not actually setting the box to checked when a category is already selected). To fix this you need to do something like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" value="<%= perk.id %>" name="company[perk_ids][]" id="company_perk_ids_<%= perk.id %>" <%= "checked" if @company.perk_ids.include? perk.id %> />
```

This would have been immediately obvious if rather than basing your CSS on the 'active' class you based it on the state of the checkbox with CSS like

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label { ... } # style for your checked box label
```

and then you wouldn't need the JS either since clicking on the label toggles the checkbox.

Comment: The solution works but there is another issue. If i uncheck all checkboxes it still returns the existing checkboxes. In other words, the checkbox array is never empty or nil. How do i make sure if all checkboxes are unchecked, it returns nothing.

Comment: @HakeemBaba That's standard HTML form behavior - an unchecked checkbox does not get submitted at all.  To work around that you need to include a hidden input with the same name prior to the checkboxes  <input type="hidden" name="company[perk_ids][]" value=""/> to act as the default submitted value if no checkboxes are checked